# pg_tables lock duration in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

When we run a query like create table  in postgresql,the dictionary table pg_tables gets locked for a certain duration.Is there any command or query using which we can track out for how long any query locks the dictionary table?

I have accessed pg_locks table but it only shows the type of lock.I need to find the duration for which the pg_tables is locked by an executing query.

Comment: Perhaps a [high log level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) like DEBUG5 logs taking and releasing of locks

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has not any tool for lock time monitoring. We had a patch to Postgres for this purpose. Anyway - the `pg_tables` is not the table - it is view

```
postgres=# \d+ pg_tables;
                           View "pg_catalog.pg_tables"
+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
|   Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Description |
+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
| schemaname  | name    |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| tablename   | name    |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| tableowner  | name    |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| tablespace  | name    |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| hasindexes  | boolean |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| hasrules    | boolean |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| hastriggers | boolean |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| rowsecurity | boolean |           |          |         | plain   |             |
+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
View definition:
 SELECT n.nspname AS schemaname,
    c.relname AS tablename,
    pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) AS tableowner,
    t.spcname AS tablespace,
    c.relhasindex AS hasindexes,
    c.relhasrules AS hasrules,
    c.relhastriggers AS hastriggers,
    c.relrowsecurity AS rowsecurity
   FROM pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace t ON tpostgres=# \d+ pg_tables;
                           View "pg_catalog.pg_tables"
+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
|   Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Description |
+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
| schemaname  | name    |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| tablename   | name    |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| tableowner  | name    |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| tablespace  | name    |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| hasindexes  | boolean |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| hasrules    | boolean |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| hastriggers | boolean |           |          |         | plain   |             |
| rowsecurity | boolean |           |          |         | plain   |             |
+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
View definition:
 SELECT n.nspname AS schemaname,
    c.relname AS tablename,
    pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) AS tableowner,
    t.spcname AS tablespace,
    c.relhasindex AS hasindexes,
    c.relhasrules AS hasrules,
    c.relhastriggers AS hastriggers,
    c.relrowsecurity AS rowsecurity
   FROM pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace t ON t.oid = c.reltablespace
  WHERE c.relkind = ANY (ARRAY['r'::"char", 'p'::"char"]);
 .oid = c.reltablespace
  WHERE c.relkind = ANY (ARRAY['r'::"char", 'p'::"char"]);
```

You can check if one or more from these tables are not locked - there should be only few operations that can lock these tables against reading. More documentation about it https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring